# Use .htaccess to replace after the first slash but keep query

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following link:

http://example.net/invite/12345

I need to replace it to http://example.net/wedding/index.php?main_page=invite&invite_code=12345

I've got the following....but I'm just not hitting the nail here.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /wedding/index.php?main_page=invite&invite_code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It's taking me to:

http:///example.net/wedding/index.php?main_page=invite&invite_code=invite%2F12345

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` is a reference to the capturing group `(.*)`, so:

```
RewriteRule ^invite/(.*)$ /wedding/index.php?main_page=invite&invite_code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm...Maybe a server configuration, but it didn't work. I had to change it to this:
    RewriteRule ^invite/(.*)$ wedding/index.php?main_page=invite&invite_code=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @StuyvesantBlue, yes, my bad! the fist `/` is not needed. I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet - I thought it was just a small oversight! Thanks!